# Save Asciidoctor AST as an AsciiDoc text document

Tags: asciidoctor

Working with Asciidoc programmatically (I'm using AsciiDoctorJ), is there a straightforward way to get back the AsciiDoc text data from the AST DOM?

I can get the pre-processed AsciiDoc stream from the pre-processor, but if I want to make any changes to the AST as it's being loaded, I don't see any way to render a `Document` back into the AsciiDoc form.

I suppose it's possible to implement a `Converter`, or simply traverse the DOM tree and write out its contents as AsciiDoc text myself, but that's a serious undertaking, and there are lot of nooks and crannies that I'm bound to miss.

Considering that AsciiDoc code contains the information that lets it determine how to convert the text into the tree, I was wondering if there is a straightforward way to simply reverse that.

Answer (score 2):

The Asciidoctor parser does not currently store enough information to reproduce the original source document. For more information, see: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/3312

Depending on what you want to achieve, the best option is probably to use a Preprocessor extension to process the raw AsciiDoc before Asciidoctor parses it: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctorj/latest/extensions/preprocessor/